# eliminate bootstrap hover and focus visibility

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, focus

I have a set of buttons that I am using as check buttons as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="slct-A" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">A</button>
    <button type="button" id="slct-B" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">B</button>
    <button type="button" id="slct-C" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">C</button>
</div>
```

The user should always be able to see what button is "pressed" (i.e. "active")  and what isn't and bootstrap 3 does this by making the "active" state darker than the non "active" state. My problem is that bootstrap also changes the backfround color in the hover and focus states, so when the user presses the button he does not see the state change, until he clicks away. As suggested in other threads, I patched around this problem by calling trigger("blur") at the end of the "click" handler - but still when the user presses the button he does not get immediate feedback that the button has been pressed since he only sees the "hover" background color. I can't reprogram the hover color in css since I want the color to be dynamic depend on the current active state irrespective of hovering. Thanks. I did see some suggestions that from what I understood means changing my version of bootstrap - I really don't want to do that....I'd appreciate your help...

Comment: Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your own btn-class to solve this issue like i did here:

---

CSS:

```
.btn-myown {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}
.btn-myown.active {
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
}
.btn-myown:hover {
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
}
```

---

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-myown" id="slct-A" type="button" data-toggle="button">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-myown" id="slct-B" type="button" data-toggle="button">B</button>
    <button class="btn btn-myown" id="slct-C" type="button" data-toggle="button">C</button>
</div>
```

---

> Bootply: https://www.bootply.com/yhoEhJdyCx

Comment: So I assume that there is no fix -  thanks for the solution - I prefer the following since it gives me what I want - a hover state emphasis by changing the border color and width but not impacting the background color.

.btn-myown {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-width:1px;
}
.btn-myown.active {
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
  padding: 6px 12px;
    border-width:1px;
}
.btn-myown:hover {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-width:2px;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

Comment: I'm a stack overflow newbie - how do I do that ?

Comment: Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to learn more about "someone answers" take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)